# Looping over mongodb aggregate -- what is the better way?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, loops, aggregate

I'm trying to run multiple aggregations on an array of objects, and then once it is finished, trigger a return next()

Here is the code:

```
}, (req, res, next) => {

//Grab the average price for each product
for(let i=0; i<res.locals.masterProductArray.length; i++){

    Product.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                item_oid: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(res.locals.masterProductArray[i].item_oid)
            },
        },
        {
            $group: {
                "_id":          "$item_oid",
                "Prices":       { $avg: "$price" },
                "Units":        { $sum: "$units" }
            }
        }
    ], (err, doc) => {

        //Handle empty results
        if(!doc[0]){
            res.locals.liveProducts.push({"_id":res.locals.masterProductArray[i].item_oid, "Prices":0,})
        }

        if(doc[0]){
            res.locals.liveProducts.push(doc[0])
        }

        if(res.locals.masterPhaseArray.length == i+1){
            return next()
        }   
    })
}
}, (req, res, next) => {
```

**The issue:** sometimes the `return next()` fires too soon, passing to the next phase before this is complete... I know looping like this is a bad idea, and the if-statement is bad idea, but I don't know what else to do.

Is there a better way to do this pattern?